# How to automaticly copy & paste fields from excel into a website form

Tags: excel, copy, webforms

I have about 50 excel sheets to input on a website everyday, but unfortunately I can only submit 8 of these sheets per hour. Therefore, I'm looking for a tool, or comnbination of tools, that will allow me to automaticly copy &  paste fields from Excel sheets, into a designated form on a website, and will allow me to set the time when every action should be completed.

The whole process can be done with just using the keyboard (using tab & several shortcuts), so maybe an automated script for keyboard commands is just what I need..

I really don't have much expierence with automated scripts etc, so if you got a suggestion, or a link, it would be much apreciated!

Thanks

Thomas

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AutoIt](http://www.autoitscript.com/autoit3/) or [PowerPro](http://powerpro.webeddie.com/) to do this kind of scripting.

More efficient, however, if the data is in a consistent table layout, is to use the Excel ODBC driver, and write a program to import the data. This will be more reliable than automating keystrokes, but will take more programming know-how.